# Submit all form data using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

For long I've been using AJAX with JQuery to submit my form data to backend code. Recently I've to deal with forms with lots of fields and thus want to see if there is any easier way to pass this data than below -

```
var url = "backend code url";
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    'firstname': $('#firstName').val(),
    // 25-30 form fields
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function (txt) {
    // success procedure
    } else {
      // error procedure
    }
  });
```

I am looking for easier way to post this data rather than mentioning each one of them in data field.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method

```
data :  $("#YourForm").serialize();
```